# change each li:eq(1,2,...) to for loop

Tags: jquery, html

how can each li:eq(0, 1,2,3,...i) change to for loop????????????????????????

```js
$(".section4 ul li:eq(0)").click(function(){
    $(".PaNel").hide();
    $("#tab1").show();
});

$(".section4 ul li:eq(1)").click(function(){
    $(".PaNel").hide();
    $("#tab2").show();
});

$(".section4 ul li:eq(2)").click(function(){
    $(".PaNel").hide();
    $("#tab3").show();
});

$(".section4 ul li:eq(3)").click(function(){
    $(".PaNel").hide();
    $("#tab4").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section4">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#none"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <article class="PaNel" id="tab1">
    </article>
    <article class="PaNel" id="tab2">
    </article>
    <article class="PaNel" id="tab3">
    </article>
    <article class="PaNel" id="tab4">
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of for loop at all, use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to generate the `id` value within the handler.

```
$(".section4 ul li").click(function(){
    $(".PaNel").hide();
    $("#tab" + ($(this).index() + 1)).show();
});
```

---

Or one linear code with chaining using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
$(".section4 ul li").click(function(){
    $(".PaNel").hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Comment: @HesungYoon : glad to help :)